# Capistrano; Check if server is primary

Tags: capistrano3, drush

So, I run some commands with Drush (Drupal) on the primary server post deployment (cache clearing, database updating, etc).

I have a block in my deploy.rb like so;

```
after :restart, :clear_cache do
  on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    symlink_configuration.each do |config|
      shared = File.join(shared_path, config[0])
      release = File.join(release_path, config[1])
      execute "ln -nfs #{shared} #{release}"
    end

    # Drush tasks.
    execute "drush -r #{File.join(release_path, 'app')} vset --exact --yes maintenance_mode 1; true"
    execute "drush -r #{File.join(release_path, 'app')} cc all; true"
    execute "drush -r #{File.join(release_path, 'app')} -y updb; true"
    execute "drush -r #{File.join(release_path, 'app')} vset --exact --yes maintenance_mode 0; true"
  end
end
```

The problem is that I want to perform those tasks on the primary server only. I have marked `primary: true` in production.rb but I can't see how I could wrap the block in `if(is(primary))` or something similar.

Would appreciate any assistance here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
on primary roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
```

You can see an example of primary used in the capistrano db migrate task
https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake

Comment: close, it seems to be `on primary, in .... ` - cant use it with roles clause it seems.

Comment: I think it should be: `on primary(:web), ...`

Comment: on primary is correct however it takes a simple and roles(:web) will come back with the server info. You could do something like that by doing a fetch however. `on primary fetch(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do` and then use set to set the varable to what ever you want `set :web, :primary_web`